# Capturing dynamic POST data from AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form that is used for live filtering of data that gets thrown into a view. I just learned of serialize() and as I understand it, it takes all the form data and turns it into a string that I can pass into the data: field in my ajax function.

So my form is set up like this in pseudo-code:

```
<?php foreach (city that's returned from a distinct select statement): ?>
    <?php echo form_checkbox('city-'.$i++, etc...) ?>
```

Which renders:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="city-1" name="city-1" class="filter city-filter">
<input type="checkbox" id="city-2" name="city-2" class="filter city-filter">
<input type="checkbox" id="city-3" name="city-3" class="filter city-filter">
```

Currently my model has a function intended to take this data and dynmically build a sql statement as so:

```
public function filter_assocaitions($cities, $class, $types)
{
    $this-db->select()->from('Associations')->where('Deleted', 0);

    if(isset($cities))
    {
        $this->db->where('City', any of the city or cities that get passed from ajax);
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with CI and php to get ajax to hook to my controller to write the proper select function.

Because as new records get added in my table with new distinct city names, more inputs will be rendered. Can I use serialize to neatly wrap all that up together to pass to ajax and if so how do i use it in my CI model to use the data to dynamically build a SQL statement with a bunch of WHERE clauses based on each city that's checked?

I also have other category of filters such as class, type that need to be included in the same SQL statement.

if this doesn't make any sense I can update this with better info.

Update: Ajax code

```
$("input.filter").change(function(){
    var data = $("form#refine-associations").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('association/refine/'.$status) ?>",
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX code??

Comment: @Abdulla - edited into the question above

Comment: what is error or output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably change the names of the City checkboxes to pass the data as an array and store the city ID as the value:

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('cities[]',$i,etc...) ?>
```

HTML Result:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="city-1" name="cities[]" value=1 class="filter city-filter">
<input type="checkbox" id="city-2" name="cities[]" value=2 class="filter city-filter">
<input type="checkbox" id="city-3" name="cities[]" value=3 class="filter city-filter">
```

And then in your model:

```
foreach($cities as $city)
{
    $this->db->or_where('City', $city);
}
```

Rough and from memory - but that should get you pretty close.